How to setup default PR Template in GitKRaken
I have create a PR template pull_request_template.md in the .github directory and merged that into my default branch. So when I create a PR in GitHub it correctly adds the template to the Description by default.
But when I create a PR in GitKraken, it only displays the Template drop down - with my template as the only option.

How can I just have GitKraken auto populate that template in the Description field just like GitHub does?
